# How to decompile a specific method generating the same code when decompiled via DecompileTypeAsString

Tags: c#, ilspy

NOOB with ILSPY

I'm trying to decompile a method via ILSpy. When I use the following, I get the code re-generated that is pretty close to what was typed in the original C#

```
decompiler.DecompileTypeAsString(new FullTypeName($@"{MyFullTypeName}"));
```

The generated code looks something like follows.

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList> FuncName(parameterList)
{
//Actual code body
}
```

Whereas when I use the following snippet,

```
string functionName = "ReflectionNamed__5";
var name = new FullTypeName(functionName);
ITypeDefinition typeInfo = decompiler.TypeSystem.MainModule.Compilation.FindType(name).GetDefinition();
if (typeInfo.Methods.First().HasBody)
{
    var tokenOfFirstMethod = typeInfo.Methods.First().MetadataToken;
    var methodCodeString = decompiler.DecompileAsString(tokenOfFirstMethod);
    Console.WriteLine(methodCodeString);
}
```

The code generated is as following:

```
//Using statements

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        int num = <>1__state;
        IReadOnlyList<string> result;
        try
        {
                if (num != 0)
                {
                        //Abstraction of a using statement
                }
                try
                {
                        TaskAwaiter<IReadOnlyList<string>> awaiter;
                        if (num != 0)
                        {
                                //Somewhat resembles the actual code
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                awaiter = <>u__1;
                                <>u__1 = default(TaskAwaiter<IReadOnlyList<string>>);
                                num = (<>1__state = -1);
                        }
                        result = awaiter.GetResult();
                }
                finally
                {
                        if (num < 0 && <oLogger>5__2 != null)
                        {
                                <oLogger>5__2.Dispose();
                        }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
                <>1__state = -2;
                <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
                return;
        }
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
    }
```

Is there a way to generate the code as generated by DecompileTypeAsString by decompiling only one function?

Comment: Telerik JustCompile might have a better time with this code.

Comment: One is giving you the compiler generated `IAsyncStatemachine`, the other is giving you a more representative version of the original code with an async method.

Comment: @MichaelRandall true, the scenario I am trying to solve is, given the reflection name, generate the representative version of the code. If I decompile a method, the compiler generated version is not really human readable. Another approach I was thinking of was to generate a method signature from reflection name and then regex find the code from representative version. Definitely an ugly approach, open to suggestions in case there is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I filed an issue on ILSpy and it has been marked as enhancement. So guess it isn't possible at the moment.

I'll go the ugly regex route for now and check back in on the enhancement in later versions.

https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/issues/1935

Comment: What is the "ugly regex route"?